# Stop deserialization if condition met in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I Have a pack of files with structure like this

```
{
  "identifier": "Test",
  "persons": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "firstName": "Max",
      "lastName": "Test1",
      ...
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "firstName": "Anne",
      "lastName": "Test1"
    }
    ...
  ],
  "relations": [
    {
      "identifier": "1",
      "partnerFirst": "1",
      "partnerSecond": "2",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "adopted": false
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "adopted": false
        }
      ],
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

And I've created custom Deserializer for Person and Relation.
Creation of persons are fine.

Can I any possibility in Relation Deserialiser to access Person Lists for searching reference ?

I search also a way to stop serializing whole file if "identifier" for some external condition, like I have in my DB this id set as "ignore".

For now I'm doing it by JSONparser before I run Deserialisation via custom Deserialiser. But Is it a way to provide to Deserialiser other Helper class ?

Comment: Not really, no. At least I don't know of a JSON parser that has that feature. What you should do is parse the raw JSON first, then map to a different data structure once you have all the data.

Comment: Usually, a posted question should contain a single question only. You have asked two, separate questions. I suggest that you [edit] this question so that it only asks about relations and post a new question regarding stopping the serialization process in the middle. Having said that, regarding the second question, perhaps this will help: [JSON Parsing with use of Streaming API and Json Parser - Mixed mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178526/json-parsing-with-use-of-streaming-api-and-json-parser-mixed-mode)

Comment: @Jorn It seem that it will be easier doing it "manualy" via JsonParser, because i have full controll of data.